# VLOOKUP exact value and closest date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, xlookup

I have different water tanks and 2 employees who measures the water tanks. Sometimes they measure the volume of the tank on the same day and sometimes not. I want to see how much their measurements differed. I understand sometimes the dates are not the same, thus, I would like to vlookup the volume of an exact tank to the closest date possible of Bob's reading dates.

Bob's Readings

| Water_Tank_Name | Date | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 15/02/2021 | 300 |
| Blue | 15/02/2021 | 145 |
| Red | 21/02/2021 | 280 |
| Red | 04/03/2021 | 339 |
| Blue | 05/03/2021 | 170 |

---

Sarah's Readings

| Water_Tank_Name | Date | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 15/02/2021 | 148 |
| Blue | 19/02/2021 | 190 |
| Red | 23/02/2021 | 294 |
| Blue | 01/03/2021 | 140 |

I used `xlookup` but that only returns a value if the exact `Water_Tank_Name` and exact `Date` return a value. However, I would like to exactly watch the `Water_Tank_Name` and match to the closet `Date`.

```
=XLOOKUP(Bob!A2 & Bob!A2, Sarah!A:A & Sarah!B:B, Sarah!C:C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use (with Excel 365):

```
=LET( tf, Bob!A2, df, Bob!B2,
      tS, Sarah!A:A, dS,Sarah!B:B, dV, Sarah!C:C,
       L, tS & dS,
       S, SIGN(ABS(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(tf & df, L, dS,,-1)-df, 999)) - ABS(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(tf & df, L, dS,,1)-df, 999))),
       XLOOKUP(tf & df, L, dV,,S) )
```

Where **tf** is the tank identity that you want use for the search and **df** is the date value that you want to search. This finds the nearest date and determines if it is smaller or larger than df and then tells the XLOOKUP to search for the next larger or smaller (**S** is either 1 or -1) that will arrive at the nearest date. It might be possible to replace the two XLOOKUPs for S with FILTERs, but I am not sure if it would be faster. *The use of whole columns for SARAH should be replaced with Excel table columns - otherwise, it will run slow.*

Answer (score 0):

I am almost positive there is something that is less verbose than this monstrosity, but it works and makes sense if you take it apart piece by piece.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($EG$12:$EG$15,$EE$12:$EE$15=$EE5)*$EF$12:$EF$15=$EF5+MIN(ABS(EF5-FILTER($EF$12:$EF$15, $EE$12:$EE$15=$EE5))))),FILTER($EG$12:$EG$15,($EE$12:$EE$15=$EE5)*($EF$12:$EF$15=$EF5-MIN(ABS(EF5-FILTER($EF$12:$EF$15, $EE$12:$EE$15=$EE5))))))
```

[image]